# Using Env.php to Override Module Status in Config.php

Tags: magento2.4, configuration, best-practice

What I am trying to achieve is overriding specific modules declared as enabled in the `app/etc/config.php` to be disabled by the `app/etc/env.php` file.

A use case of that would be the 2FA module which I prefer to keep as disabled in the development environments.

I tried adding the module to the `env.php` file as follows, but the `config.php` gets updated to `0` as well:

```
<?php
return [
    'modules' => [
        'Magento_TwoFactorAuth' => 0,
        'Vendor_DevModuleWhichShallNotBeTrackedByTheConfigFile' => 0
    ],
    ...
];
```

What would be the **best practice** for this situation? Should I remove the module from the `config.php` entirely and add it to each server `env.php` file separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can not enable/disable the module using `env.php` file, you have two options here:

1. Disable modules config (using config path) in `env.php`
2. Keep the 2FA modules enabled in `config.php` and disable the modules during the deployment in your CI process using:

```bash
bin/magento module:disable MODULE_NAME
```

Comment: For the first option, do you mean like the `web\secure\base_url` config? The second option will update the `config.php` file to the same status which makes it hard to keep the file updated in git especially if I have many modules disabled for development purposes (not only 2FA)

Comment: That's correct, you can disable most of the features in Magento with config paths, like `web\secure\base_url`

Comment: That's great for most of the modules, thanks Ahmed. However, I've tested this method for the 2FA module specifically and it doesn't do the job. I guess since the config variable `twofactorauth/general/enabled` is not being used correctly in the module (or maybe intentionally to enforce 2FA)